Postgresql Trigger Error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
I have a PostgreSQL database with this function enabled. The function should automatically populate the num_accessione field using values from other fields, as can be seen from the code.
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dati_raccolta_pop_accessione()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
    $datiraccoltapopaccessione$
    BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP='INSERT') THEN
            UPDATE dati_raccolta
            SET num_accessione = (
                SELECT
                    CASE
                        WHEN interesse_agricolo = 'si' THEN
                            CONCAT(
                                banca_germoplasma, '_A_', 
                                REGEXP_REPLACE(data_raccolta::text, '-', '', 'g'), '_', gid, '_',
                                UPPER(
                                    REGEXP_REPLACE(
                                        REGEXP_REPLACE(nome_raccoglitore, '\y(\w)\w*', '\1', 'g'), 
                                        '\s+', '', 'g'
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        WHEN interesse_agricolo = 'no' THEN
                            CONCAT(
                                banca_germoplasma, '_N_', 
                                REGEXP_REPLACE(data_raccolta::text, '-', '', 'g'), '_', gid, '_',
                                UPPER(
                                    REGEXP_REPLACE(
                                        REGEXP_REPLACE(nome_raccoglitore, '\y(\w)\w*', '\1', 'g'), 
                                        '\s+', '', 'g'
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                    END
                FROM dati_raccolta
            );
        ELSIF (TG_OP='UPDATE') THEN
            UPDATE dati_raccolta AS t
            SET num_accessione = (
                SELECT
                    CASE
                        WHEN interesse_agricolo = 'si' THEN
                            CONCAT(
                                banca_germoplasma, '_A_', 
                                REGEXP_REPLACE(data_raccolta::text, '-', '', 'g'), '_', gid, '_',
                                UPPER(
                                    REGEXP_REPLACE(
                                        REGEXP_REPLACE(nome_raccoglitore, '\y(\w)\w*', '\1', 'g'), 
                                        '\s+', '', 'g'
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        WHEN interesse_agricolo = 'no' THEN
                            CONCAT(
                                banca_germoplasma, '_N_', 
                                REGEXP_REPLACE(data_raccolta::text, '-', '', 'g'), '_', gid, '_',
                                UPPER(
                                    REGEXP_REPLACE(
                                        REGEXP_REPLACE(nome_raccoglitore, '\y(\w)\w*', '\1', 'g'), 
                                        '\s+', '', 'g'
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                    END
                FROM dati_raccolta
            );
        END IF;
        
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $datiraccoltapopaccessione$ 
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    
    
    
    CREATE TRIGGER dati_raccolta_pop_num_accessione_insert
    AFTER INSERT ON dati_raccolta
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE dati_raccolta_pop_accessione();
    
    CREATE TRIGGER dati_raccolta_pop_num_accessione_update
    AFTER UPDATE ON dati_raccolta
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD.geom IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.geom)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE dati_raccolta_pop_accessione();


Unfortunately, I receive the following error:
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE dati_raccolta
SET num_accessione = (
SELECT
CASE
WHEN interesse_agricolo = 'si' THEN
CONCAT(
banca_germoplasma, 'A',
REGEXP_REPLACE(data_raccolta::text, '-', '', 'g'), '', gid, '',
UPPER(
REGEXP_REPLACE(
REGEXP_REPLACE(nome_raccoglitore, '\y(\w)\w*', '\1', 'g'),
'\s+', '', 'g'
)
)
)
WHEN interesse_agricolo = 'no' THEN
CONCAT(
banca_germoplasma, 'N',
REGEXP_REPLACE(data_raccolta::text, '-', '', 'g'), '', gid, '',
UPPER(
REGEXP_REPLACE(
REGEXP_REPLACE(nome_raccoglitore, '\y(\w)\w*', '\1', 'g'),
'\s+', '', 'g'
)
)
)
END
FROM dati_raccolta
)"
PL/pgSQL function dati_raccolta_pop_accessione() line 4 at SQL statement

Pretty straight forward, ...more than one row returned by a subquery....  SET num_accessione =  can only accept one value at a time and your sub-queries are obviously returning more then one at a time.

I've removed the SELECT statement from the function and now it works. However, the function updates all the rows in the table instead of updating only the newly inserted rows.

Define a before insert trigger and use NEW.num_accessione := ... instead of update dati_raccolta SET num_accessione = ...

Read plpgsql triggers. Use BEFORE UPDATE trigger and assign the desired value to NEW.num_accessione and then RETURN NEW.

Here the solution for the insert steatment:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dati_raccolta_pop_accessione()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$datiraccoltapopaccessione$
DECLARE
    accessione_calcolata TEXT;
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP='INSERT') THEN
        accessione_calcolata := (
                CASE
                    WHEN NEW.interesse_agricolo = 'si' THEN concat(NEW.banca_germoplasma, '_A_', REGEXP_REPLACE(NEW.data_raccolta::text, '-', '', 'g'), '_', NEW.gid, '_', 
                        UPPER (
                            REGEXP_REPLACE (
                                REGEXP_REPLACE (NEW.nome_raccoglitore, '\y(\w)\w*', '\1', 'g'),'\s+', '', 'g'
                                )
                            )
                        ) 
                    WHEN NEW.interesse_agricolo = 'no' THEN concat(NEW.banca_germoplasma, '_N_', REGEXP_REPLACE(NEW.data_raccolta::text, '-', '', 'g'), '_', NEW.gid, '_', 
                        UPPER (
                            REGEXP_REPLACE (
                                REGEXP_REPLACE (NEW.nome_raccoglitore, '\y(\w)\w*', '\1', 'g'),'\s+', '', 'g'
                                )
                            )
                        )
                END
        );
    END IF;
    
    NEW.num_accessione := accessione_calcolata;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$datiraccoltapopaccessione$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER dati_raccolta_pop_num_accessione_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON dati_raccolta
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION dati_raccolta_pop_accessione();



You don't need the IF (TG_OP='INSERT') as there is only one operation defined for the trigger. 2) Simplify, use NEW.accessione_calcolata := ( .... Then  you can eliminate the DECLARE  accessione_calcolata TEXT; and NEW.num_accessione := accessione_calcolata;.

